# How can I iterate through a function with for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to pass the 'y' variable to okayid but there seems to be a problem with the looping. The loop works fine with the first call of 'y' on okay.item(y) but it is not looping through okayid.item(y). It seemed to me like it was a scope problem but I am not sure.

```
var okay = document.getElementsByClassName("Okay");
var okayid = document.getElementsByClassName("OkayID");

var numberOkays = okay.length;

        for(y = 0; y <= numberOkays; y++){
            okay.item(y).onclick = function(){

                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        alert('vote Sent to picture with id = ' + okayid.item(y).innerHTML);
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/vote.php", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            };
        }
```

Here is the html ...

```
<a class="Link1A Okay" href="#"><span class="OkayID">[id]</span><div class="Vote1A">Okay</div></a>
```

Comment: `y` is a **global** variable, you didn't use the `var` keyword, so it's accessible everywhere ?

Comment: Your issue is closures, scope and asynchronicity, and you should start here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Comment: It should be noted that your issue could simply be solved by doing `this.innerHTML` instead !

Comment: I tried `this.innerHTML` but it returns HTML instead of [id]. @adeneo I think it's closures too, I tried returning the alert but It won't loop through 2nd function.

Comment: If you want the ID, just do `this.id`

Comment: @adeneo I have identify the problem. When I pass 'y' to the first function it works but it does not iterate, it only passes the first result. So in this solution when I click on Okay, I only get the first OkayID. I will post the solution in the answer area ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got lots if issues.

- in the for loop, you don't init `y` with `var` which could cause problems, as now `y` is part of the global scope.
- in the for loop, you have `y <= numberOkays` which will cause an empty element to be retrieved at the end since numberOkays is the result of the array's length.  So you'd get okay[y] is undefined at the end.
- You don't need to retrieve the okays at the onset, you can just get the appropriate element in the onclick event.
- After the loops are done `y` will be at the last index, so when the click event is fired you'd always get the last element when you refer to the `Okay[y]` (or in your case you'll just get undefined because of problem 2).  Using this will refer to the element clicked which effectively what you intended with `Okay[y]`.

Here's an updated version of your code, with a link to a working jsFiddle below:

```
var okay = document.getElementsByClassName("Okay");

for(var y = 0; y < okay.length; y++){
    okay[y].onclick = function(){  
        idElem = this.getElementsByClassName("OkayID")[0];

        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                alert('vote Sent to picture with id = ' + idElem.innerHTML);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/vote.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    };
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp91ue3c/)

Comment: It works perfectly. But what I don't understand are these two things:
1. What does 'this' refer to?
2. And why did you set it's index to 0? not x for example

Comment: 1) in this context `this` refers to the element that was clicked.  You should read about `this` as it isn't the same as it is in other languages. 2) I set it to 0, because I wanted to get the first element with className OkayID.  `this` is the parent element with the `Okay` class.